How to compute the vector field from a potential in the complex plane?
I am watching this Youtube video and I have the following dumb question around 1:18:00: How do you draw the vector field for a given potential in the complex plane? He gives the potential $V(x) = x^4-x^2$ and claims that the dynamics look like this in the complex $x$ plane:

That is, ellipse-looking figures going around branch cuts on the real axis where the potential wells are.
He gives the potential $V(x) = x^4 - x^2$, and I presume we have the energy $E = p^2 +x^4 - x^2$, so the dynamics should be given by solving the differential equation $\frac{dx}{dt} = \sqrt{E - x^4+x^2}$ ... right?
But if I try to plot this, I get a figure that looks like this:

Am I misunderstanding some physics here, or what it means to "plot the dynamics in the complex plane" or what? I want to be able to reproduce his plot myself for some different potentials.
Edit: Image in response to LPZ's comment:

What's the value of $E$ in the plots?

@LPZ I see that if $z=x+ip$ then $E$ is this expression but without the square root. However I don't see why the complex plane would be $x+ip$, and when I plot the isolines of this energy, I get a family of isolines that cross the imaginary axis. (the E=0 one being a lemniscate thingy). Shouldn't I have two isolated families corresponding to the two wells?

Possibly I am not asking the question correctly... I think I am just making $x$ complex, not plotting the trajectories in phase space or something like that. So if I have an initial condition where $x$ is real, it should just go back and forth in one of the wells, but if I put $x_0$ outside the well it should trace out these ellipses around the turning points

@Qmechanic That one is E = 1. If I use E = -0.1 so that $\min(V)<E<0$ that seems to look a little better, but still not quite what I expect because the trajectories on with $Re(z_0)>0$ all crash back into the real axis, and the trajectories with $Re(z_0)<0$ go towards the origin.

What did you plot exactly, I rather obtained something like this:

which is compatible with the lecture. The velocity field is:
$$
\dot z = w := \sqrt{E-V(z)}
$$
with $\min V<E<0$. Since it is analytic except at the branch points where $V(z)=E$, the trajectories can be viewed as the level lines of a suitable stream function:
$$
w = \frac{d\Phi}{dz} \\
\Phi = \phi+i\psi
$$
with $\phi$ the potential and $\psi$ the stream function. To compute the antiderivative $\Phi$, you will need to use elliptic integrals, or use Wolfram Alpha.

Ah, this looks exactly right! So maybe I am just not plotting it right. I made a bunch of grid points X,Y using np.meshgrid, then defined a function of Z = X+iY by $E(z) = Im(z)^2 - Re(z)^2+Im(z)^4$, then used plt.contour to plot isolines for 10 or so values of E. I'll paste the result into my answer. How did you generate this plot?

Forgot to say my comment was wrong, I plotted the vector field $v_x = \Re\sqrt{E-V(z)},v_y = \Im\sqrt{E-V(z)})$

I'm sorry but I am even more confused now... That vector field $(v_x,v_y)$ is what I plotted initially in red. I realize I should have set $\min(V)<E<0$, but even when I do, my trajectories don't orbit the branch cuts like yours, they all move off to the right and converge onto  the real axis. Did you compute the integral curves analytically? Why would that be different than just using numerical streamlines in the plotter?

Yes, that’s normal,  the velocity field is double valued and when you cross the real in the forbidden zones you have branch cut. You need to resume the resolution on the other side with a flipped vector field. My field lines are solved numerically, and this is why I stopped them in the upper half plane

Ohhh, this is what I was missing! Plotting the original vector field in quadrants I,III and the flipped one in II,IV gave me the plot and streamlines I wanted!
